# CreateProcess method ends up with an error

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I've a problem with my following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;  
  STARTUPINFO si;     

  printf("Process %d reporting for duty\n",GetCurrentProcessId());
  GetStartupInfo(&si);
  CreateProcess(NULL,"notepad.exe", NULL,NULL,FALSE,DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL,NULL, &si, &pi);
  printf("New Process ID: %d\n",pi.dwProcessId);
  return(0);
}
```

And on the runing time,I ran this while debuggin and it crashes on the CreateProcess method,with this error message:**" Unhandled exception at 0x7c82f29c in Tests.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00415760."**
What does it means???

Comment: See also: [Why does the CreateProcess function modify its input command line? | The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090601-00/?p=18083)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

32 bit executables invariably have a base address of `0x00400000`. The address that cannot be written to, according to the exception is `0x00415760`. Which means that your code is almost certainly trying to write to a read-only part of the executable image. That happens, for example, when you try to write to string literals.

Now, the second parameter to [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) must be modifiable memory (it is declared as `LPTSTR`). But you are passing a string literal. Put `"notepad.exe"` in a modifiable buffer to solve your problem.

```
char CommandLine[] = "notepad.exe";
CreateProcess(NULL, CommandLine, ...
```

Comment: One little more question...lets say I have a .c file with some methods, and I create a new project where I need to make a process that uses the methods from the previouse project.... All under the same solution.
So, I guess that "CommandLine" parameter would stand for the .exe file created by the first program(the one with the methods I need to be use). 
Now I'm in the file with the code that I published before, how is it possible to access these methods & use them?